# What message will be sent by Windows when you press "Windows+D"

Tags: windows, winapi, message

I used SPY++ to hook my windows message, but there is no WM_SYSCOMMAND message was sent when I pressed "Windows+D". What message will be sent by Windows when you press "Windows+D"?

Comment: There is no message when your window is covered by another window. You just have to accept that other windows can cover yours. That is, after all, why the user pressed the hotkey in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

*Your* application will not get a window message at all. Win+D is a hotkey registered by Explorer.exe (the shell program that's responsible for showing the taskbar, desktop icons, etc.).

It simply uses [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) and *it* will receive a window message when you press WIN+D and will then take care of the whole show/hide thing.

Note you *can* register your own WIN+*x* hotkeys using said function but you're not supposed to and will run into problems - unless you were replacing Explorer.exe or such.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a Window-Message at all...this is most likely handled by the kernel itself.

Answer (score 0):

"Windows+D" is a hotkey combination.
Perhaps you can catch it as a [WM_HOTKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646279%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.

You can register your own hotkeys, if you want, with the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score -1):

**Windows+D** is a system wide hotkey and is reserved for use by operating system. 
Hotkeys with MOD_WIN can not be registered by RegisterHotKey API or received by WM_HOTKEY message

Comment: That is not true, RegisterHotKey can catch Win+? hotkeys just fine.

Comment: Anders, I have tried this on Windows 7 (registering fails and WM_HOTKEY is not fired), Could you confirm your platform.

Comment: It works on Vista, I have tried it. (Though not with a key combination already in use by the OS.)